# In SwiftUI, how can I set foregroundStyle color only when a certain state is true, but otherwise leave the original foreground color?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Background**

I have a Text element that I want to gray out after the user has selected it.

It's not exactly as easy it seems because my app allows user to switch between darkMode & lightMode.

**What I've Done**

1. created a toggle (Bool) variable to hold value of whether user has selected the item (`hasUserSelected`)
2. used Conditional Modifier when setting `foregroundStyle` on Text element

**Code Sample**

```
@State private var hasUserSelected = false
...

Text("This is the item")
   .foregroundStyle(hasUserSelected ? Color.grey : nil) // nil isn't valid here
```

I just want to set the foregroundStyle in the case when the user has selected the item.
Otherwise, I want the "default" foregroundStyle.

**Can't Actually Return nil**

I can't actually return nil to `.foregroundStyle`

I'd rather not save the original value in a variable and then restore it.

Is there something else I can do so that I can use the Conditional Modifier?

Is there a more direct way to handle this situation?

Comment: Use .primary instead of nil to get the default value

Comment: Try using `? .gray : .primary` instead? These are both `ShapeStyle`.

Comment: Ahh, `.primary` works great for this situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a specific solution suggested in a comment works for you - great. A more generic solution is to create a generic conditional modifier:

```
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder func applyIf<ViewOnTrue: View, ViewOnFalse: View>(_ condition: Bool, transformOnTrue: (Self) -> ViewOnTrue, transformOnFalse: (Self) -> ViewOnFalse) ->  some View {
        
        if condition {
            transformOnTrue(self)
        } else {
            transformOnFalse(self)
        }
    }
}
```

So now you can control what to do in each case:

```
    .applyIf(hasUserSelected,
           transformOnTrue: { originalView in // Apply color
                originalView.foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
            },
           transformOnFalse: { originalView in // Don't apply color
                originalView
            }
    )
```